# How to hash a binary file in Rust

Tags: rust, sha256

In rust, using `sha256 = "1.0.2"` (or similar), how do I hash a binary file (i.e. a `tar.gz` archive)?

I'm trying to get the sha256 of that binary file.

This doesn't work:

```rust
fn hash() {
    let file = "file.tar.gz";
    let computed_hash = sha256::digest_file(std::path::Path::new(file)).unwrap();
    computed_hash
}
```

the output is:

```sh
...
Error { kind: InvalidData, message: "stream did not contain valid UTF-8" }
```

Comment: After https://github.com/baoyachi/sha256-rs/pull/2 , the code you posted should work. IMO this behaviour is a bug so I made  PR

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edit:
Upgrading to `sha256 = "1.0.3"` should fix this

The issue is that `digest_file` is internally reading the file to a `String`, which requires that it contains valid UTF-8, which is obviously not what you want in this case.

Instead, you could read the file in as bytes and pass that into `sha256::digest_bytes`:

```rust
let bytes = std::fs::read(path).unwrap();  // Vec<u8>
let hash = sha256::digest_bytes(&bytes);
```

Comment: This solution works. For the sake of completion the solution provided in the rust cookbook is roughly 10 times faster: https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/cryptography/hashing.html

Answer (score 12):

The `sha2` crate upon which depends supports hashing `Read`able objects without needing to read the entire file into memory. See the example in the [hashes readme](https://github.com/RustCrypto/hashes).

```
use sha2::{Sha256, Digest};
use std::{io, fs};

let mut hasher = Sha256::new();
let mut file = fs::File::open("file.tar.gz")?;

let bytes_written = io::copy(&mut file, &mut hasher)?;
let hash_bytes = hasher.finalize();
```

Comment: Definitely better to not read the entire file into memory.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an implementation using the `sha2` crate that doesn't read the entire file into memory, and doesn't depend on the ring crate. In my case, ring isn't pure rust, which leads to cross-compilation difficulties.

```rust
use data_encoding::HEXLOWER;
use sha2::{Digest, Sha256};
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, Read};
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

/// calculates sha256 digest as lowercase hex string
fn sha256_digest(path: &PathBuf) -> Result<String> {
    let input = File::open(path)?;
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(input);

    let digest = {
        let mut hasher = Sha256::new();
        let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
        loop {
            let count = reader.read(&mut buffer)?;
            if count == 0 { break }
            hasher.update(&buffer[..count]);
        }
        hasher.finalize()
    };
    Ok(HEXLOWER.encode(digest.as_ref()))
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't need `HEXLOWER`, you can use `format!("{:X}", digest)`